# How can I get the details of ongoing file uploads to my google drive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api

I am building a web app to access the details of google drive. I would like to get the details of files that are being syncing to google drive from  Desktop. Do there is any api's for that, or any alternate methods?

Comment: @pinoyyid is there any alternate methods ?

Comment: There are no server API's that do what you're looking for. Best you can do is look at recently modified files and infer that they are active.